# How to change font of a selected text in an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am developing a notes app in android, and I have an `EditText` that I want the user to be capable of changing `font color`, `size` and `style` of a selected text(not all). Is this possible?

Comment: show code snippet... what you have did?

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-changing-text-color-of-edittext-using-edittextstyle-property/  you may try this

Comment: You can implement [this](https://github.com/tiagohm/MarkdownView) library.